# How to open The bar which shows the opened files in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

In my `pycharm` The bar which shows the opened files in the top of the editor has gone. as you see in below picture:

[image: The bar has gone]

Unfortunately, I can't find anything in the window menu and settings to solve this. I couldn't file anything with searching too.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Editor Tabs`.

In there you will be able to find the tab placement in the section `Appearance`.

`Placement` can be set to `Top` (default), `Bottom`, and so on. I imagine it is currently set to `None` for you.

You can play with a bunch of other options in this section.

Comment: Wish You answer faster! :)) I delete configure of `pycharm` and restart problem fixed, But I checked your answer and I should say it's correct. I can delete show of editor tabs with that.

Answer (score 0):

### Possibility 1: Hidden Project Window

It is called the `Project Window`. Go to

```
View -> Tool Windows -> Project
```

Or press `Alt+1`

This should make the Project Window reappear.

---

### Possibility 2: Hidden Window Tool bars

In the lower left corner of the IDE, there is a small icon, looking like this [image] or this [image]. Clicking on it should make the toolbars reappear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Unfortunately no it not working.

Comment: @SirSaleh. Ok, maybe all window toolbars are hidden. See my edited answer and click on the icon on the lower left corner. Compare [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html#show-all). If this doesn't help check that webpage further. There are many possibilities explained.

Comment: Sorry, I think I made you tired. I don't have those items! But why?? I lost many things that aren't even available in window menu!